# Why Google Analytics user count changes when adding Date dimension?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

After spending too much on Power BI trying to see why my user count didn't match when querying userAgeBracket, I used https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/ and here is the output:

start-date is 2019-11-01. end-date is 2019-11-30.

Without Date (**Notice there are users with age 55-64 and 65+**):

[image: Querying Google Analytics userAgeBracket without date dimension]

When adding Date dimension:

[image: Querying Google Analytics userAgeBracket with date dimension]

Notice there are now no users with age 55-64 and 65+.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2799357?hl=en) says:

> Thresholds are applied to prevent anyone viewing a report from
>   inferring the demographics or interests of individual users. When a
>   report contains Age, Gender, or Interest Category (as a primary or
>   secondary dimension, or as part of an applied segment), a threshold
>   may be applied and some data may be withheld from the report. For
>   example, if there are fewer than N instances of Gender=male in a
>   report, then data for the male value may be withheld.

So you won't be able in some cases to get granular demographics data in GA reports.